# How to link a created image in a webview (within html code)?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, swift3, uiimageview

I'm trying to create a webview with some data and an image (from a uimageview) that the app has previously modified. Data 'link' to webview has been easy. But the modified (and still not 'saved', because it's not necessary for the app) image hasn't got a path.

I've tried:

```
var imageToShow: UIImage!
imageToShow.image = modifiedImage

let stringHTML = "<body>\(data1)<br>\(data2)<br><imgstyle="width: 350px; height: 175px;" alt="" src="\(imageToShow)"><br></body>"// This shows app data, but not the image: \(imageToShow) is not correct

webViewToShow.loadHTMLString(stringHTML, baseURL: nil)
```

I'm new to swift (3). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why do you need a webview for this? Can't you display a simple `UIViewController` with two `UILabel`s and an `UIImageView`?

Comment: @Losiowaty I want to create a PDF file with different types of data (labels, images). In my project there are a few more 'datas' (about 200), but I have only problems with the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you are looking for, try following:

1. Write the image to a directory. eg mofifiedImage.png
2. Load UIWebView with html string with baseURL set to the directory where image is stored

   let stringHTML = "<\img src='mofifiedImage.png'>"
   webViewToShow.loadHTMLString(stringHTML, baseURL: nil)
3. whenever image is modified reload the UIWebView

Comment: Thank you. I'm having problems with linking (html code) with the image. I will let you know how it ends. I was thinking of a way to do it without saving...

Comment: I'm having problems with linking (html code) with the image in 'Documents' directory (any idea?).

Comment: glad, I could help you.